# how to undo a rebase in git

Tags: git, github

I've made some changes in a branch `xyz`. But I have accidentally fixed up these changes and rebased with the HEAD~2.

How can I undo this mistake so that I can make a new commit?

Comment: There is likely a better solution, and -f should be avoided; however, you can clone at a previous commit and force a commit to override the branch future deleting the rebase

Comment: In general you can find the old versions of the commits in the `git reflog`

Comment: Yup. Just re-hang the label wherever it was before, you're done.